# How to start Main.main() in a different thread within a JUnit test

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, junit

**How can I start a separate thread which runs my project's main class from within a Junit test?**

I have a main class that instantiates `Servidor()` which ends up listening for socket connections, and works fine.

Here's Main:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            Servidor servidor = new Servidor();
            servidor.start();
        }catch(Exception ex){
            MyUtils.handle(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's `Servidor()`:

```
public class Servidor extends javax.swing.JPanel {
    private static final int PUERTO = 2020;
    private boolean running = false;

    void start() throws Exception{
    try ( ServerSocket servidor = new ServerSocket(PUERTO) ){
        running = true;
        String info = String.format("Listening@%s:%s",InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(),PUERTO);
        System.out.println(info);
        while (running)
            new ReceptorPedidosReplicacion(servidor.accept());
        System.out.println("Server Stopped");
        } 
    }

    void stop(){
        running = false;
    }
}
```

However, I designed the following Junit test and as expected, it works fine as long as I have my project running in the background:

```
public class ServidorTest {
    @Test
    public void testSendPedido() throws Exception{
        MySerializableObject pedido = new MySerializableObject();
        Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2020);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(pedido);
    }

}
```

So what I would like to do is to be able to do something like:

```
    @Test
    public void testSendPedido() throws Exception{
        Main.main(); //Option1
        new Servidor().start(); //Option 2

        MySerializableObject pedido = new MySerializableObject();
        Socket cliente = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2020);
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
        out.writeObject(pedido);
    }
```

However neither option works because `Servidor()` hijacks the execution thread and the test never gets past those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got around to it by making `Servidor()` implement `Runnable` and starting a different thread from the Junit. However, I'm not sure if Junit will handle such new threads safely. I'm guessing I'll be fine as long `Servidor` has no critical state changes. However I'm open to a better solution.

```
public class Servidor extends javax.swing.JPanel implements Runnable{
    ...
    public void run(){start()}
}
```

So the test looks like this

```
@Test
public void testSendPedido() throws Exception{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Servidor());
    thread.start();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to spawn a thread you can use the following:

```
final ExecutorService exService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
exService.execute(new Runnable() { // or use submit to get a Future (a result of computation, you'll need a Callable, rather than runnable then)
   public void run() {
    // do your arbitrary stuff
   }
});

// do stuff in the main thread.

// waits for termination for 30 seconds
exService.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
exService.shutdownNow();
```

With this construction you don't have to change your code, just place whatever you need in the `run method` and you're good to go. Note, of course it can work with lambdas like any java 8+ code, I've intentionally used the Java 7 style to show you which interfaces exactly are involved here.

Comment: This is actually really useful but it will also bloat the test code